# Runtime error when using char as int to scanf and printf

Tags: c, stack

```
int main()
{
    char ch = 0;
    int c = 0;
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    printf("%c", ch);
}
```

I can input the ASCII number and output the correct character. But the program crashes at the end of the code, the } sign.

Using Visual Studio 2019

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ch' was corrupted.

Comment: An `int` is usually 32 bits (four bytes) while a `char` usually is only 8 bits (one byte). You're asking `scanf` to write four bytes into a one-byte variable. The `%d` format expects an argument of type `int *`, and you give it an argument of type `char *`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Why do you want to scanf an int with a char?

Comment: **Undefined Behaviour** can manifest itself in amusing ways.

Comment: It seems to me from the title that you're aware you're doing something that you're not supposed to do and that this is undefined behavior. So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: The reason the system prints the message “Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ch' was corrupted.” is that the stack around the variable `ch` was corrupted.

Comment: ... and the reason the stack round the variable 'ch' was corrupted is explained in the very first comment.

Comment: Okay - so you know that you are doing it wrong, you know what you are doing wrong and now you are asking.... what? Why it isn't working? Kind of strange...

Comment: You are standing on one side of the street at a busy intersection.  The sign says DON'T WALK.  Remembering a classic scene from the movie [Bowfinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowfinger), you dart across the street anyway.  Miraculously, none of the cars whizzing by in the six lanes of high-speed traffic hit you.  You make it to the other side safely.  There, a policeman who has observed this spectacle writes you a warning ticket, citing your reckless behavior.  Why did he write you a ticket?  You made it across the street safely.

Answer (score 1):

Since `scanf` has non-existent type safety, it can't know the type of parameters passed (one reason why the format string is there in the first place).

The stack corruption is caused by you lying to the compiler here: `scanf("%d", &ch);`. You tell it "trust me, ch is an int". But it isn't. So scanf tries to store 4 bytes in an area where only 1 byte is allocated and you get a crash.

Decent compilers can warn for incorrect format specifiers.

Comment: *Decent compilers can warn for incorrect format specifiers.* indeed, if you ask gently with `-Wall` or `-Weverything` :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- missing `#include <stdio.h>` ;
- unused variable `c` ;
- type mismatch passing a `char` variable address when `scanf()` expects an `int *` for the `%d` conversion specifier ;
- missing test on `scanf()` return value ;
- missing newline at the end of the output ;
- missing `return 0;` (implied as of c99, but sloppy).

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ch;
    if (scanf("%d", &ch) == 1) {
        printf("%c\n", ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question was not, "What did I do wrong?", or "Why didn't it work?".
I guess your question is, "Why *did* it work?", or, "Why did it print an error message *after* seeming to work correctly?"

There are lots of mistakes you can make which will corrupt the stack.  This is one of them.  Much of the time, these errors are rather inscrutable: If the memory corruption is severe enough that the memory management hardware can detect it, you may get a generic message like "Segmentation violation" at the instant the bad access occurs, but if not, if the damage isn't bad enough to cause any overt problems, your program may seem to work as you expected, despite the error.

It would be prohibitively expensive to perform explicit tests (in software) to check the stack for damage during every operation.  Therefore, no attempt is made to do so, and the primary responsibility is placed on you, the programmer, not to do obviously wrong things like telling `scanf` to store an `int` in a `char`-sized box.

In this case, your system *did* make a check for stack damage, but as some kind of a one-time operation, only *after* the `main` function had returned.  That's why the `scanf` and the `printf` seemed to work correctly, and the error message seemed to coincide with the closing `}` at the end of `main`.

Echoing an analogy I made in a comment, this is sort of like having a policeman write you a ticket for having done something dangerous that did not cause an accident.  Why not write the ticket *as* you are doing the dangerous thing?  Why write the ticket after the fact at all, since your dangerous behavior didn't cause an accident?  Well, because sometimes that's just the way the world works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to input an integer and print its char value so in my opinion this is what you are trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("%c", c);

    return 0;
}
```

***Note:** This is a C++ code but the syntax inside main function will work for C language as well*